How could I make ansible connection parameters dependent on the controller host?
There are various reasons where I would like to execute ansible on many different systems, in different configurations. Some example:

Executing ansible on one of the hosts existing in the inventory, a "local" connection with a sudo "become" would be better than a self-connecting ssh.
Various hosts might have different firewall rules to handle (thus, ssh jumphosts or non-standard ports might be needed where usually an ordinary ssh connection would be enough)
Similarly in a virtualization/containerization structure, various local rpc tools might preferred, maybe even their chaining (like a "docker exec" or "oc rsh"), also in position-different configurations.

What is the best to handle this? I think, somehow the ansible connection variables should be dependent on the executing hosts.

I understand that you want to customize your connection depending on the host.
Does this fit your requirements ?
[all]
localhost ansible_connection=local ansible_become=yes
server1 ansible_host=192.168.1.10 ansible_user=admin ansible_port=2222 ansible_ssh_common_args='-o ProxyJump=jumphost'
container1 ansible_connection=docker

EDIT

To apply different settings based on the controller host, you can use conditionals in your playbooks or dynamic inventory scripts to adjust the connection parameters accordingly.

Conditional parameters
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Example task for localhost
      debug:
        msg: "This is the localhost"
      when: inventory_hostname == 'localhost'

    - name: Example task for server1
      debug:
        msg: "This is server1"
      when: inventory_hostname == 'server1'

    - name: Example task for container1
      debug:
        msg: "This is container1"
      when: inventory_hostname == 'container1'

Dynamic inventory
#!/usr/bin/env python

import json

inventory = {
    'all': {
        'hosts': ['localhost', 'server1', 'container1'],
        'vars': {
            'ansible_become': 'yes'
        }
    },
    '_meta': {
        'hostvars': {
            'localhost': {
                'ansible_connection': 'local'
            },
            'server1': {
                'ansible_host': '192.168.1.10',
                'ansible_user': 'admin',
                'ansible_port': 2222,
                'ansible_ssh_common_args': '-o ProxyJump=jumphost'
            },
            'container1': {
                'ansible_connection': 'docker'
            }
        }
    }
}

print(json.dumps(inventory, indent=2))



Make the script executable then run it using Ansible.

chmod +x dynamic_inventory.py
ansible-playbook -i dynamic_inventory.py playbook.yml


Ok, it was really not very obvious that it should depend on the controller host. The second idea is to create different playbooks, that makes this whole thing also playbook-dependent, I only want it to depend on the controller host. I do not want to play this with all my playbooks. I think, your third idea is already some really usable. It needs an integration with the external caller infrastructure of the ansible, but that is not a big problem. Thanks!

Wait, I think I have a very nice idea! How about if the overlay vars (.meta.hostvars.* in your example) would be somehow integrated into the host_vars? I think, somehow a general inventory dumper script should be written, and then its output could be trivially modified? On this way, host_vars/server1.yml could contain, what to do differently if ansible is executed on server1.

My current best bet is like this:
ansible_connection: "{{ 'local' if lookup('pipe', 'hostname') == 'myclient1' else 'ssh' }}"

That will use the local connection plugin on myclient1, and ssh elsewhere.
I have no better idea, how could I somehow generate some like a host-specific override snippet to the host variables in general.

Finally I do @YassineLbk's third idea, but I use yaml instead of json. Thus, ansible is not really loving it with same native feature, but it can be done well by extending some external caller inftrastructure.
